# This weighs heavily on my mind

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, weighing

I have 9 coins that look identical, but one is heavier than the others. I want to identify that one.

My brother has an old-fashioned [balance scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_scale#Balance_scales) that I can use, but I'll have to do annoying chores for him for every time I use that scale (that is, every time I use it to compare the weights of two (sets of) coins). Can you help me find the heavier coin using the scale as little as possible?

<sub>• The scale can handle the weight of all coins together, so there is no restriction in that regard.

• Please give not only the number of times you need to weigh, but also explain what you weigh and why.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is asked before but I will give you the shortest answer possible:

> Divide coins into three, A=3,B=3,C=3, weight AvB, if they are equal, C has the heaviest one, if A weighs more, A has, otherwise B has.

Then

> Divide Heavier sets of coins again, 1v1, leaving 1 outside, if it balances the one outsite is heavier, or whichever weighs more is heavier one.

so

> Two weighing is optimal solution.